# How do I add leaflet.markercluster plugin to my code?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I’m wondering if anyone can help me.
I’m pretty new to coding and i’m trying to implement leaflets marker cluster into my site, however nothing is showing up when I add the usage from GitHub.

```js
var BPalace = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'img/icons8-marker-50.png',
  iconSize: [30, 30],
  iconAnchor: [15, 30],
  popupAnchor: [1, -30],
});

var marker1 = L.marker([51.5015385807725, -0.14176521957406812], {
  icon: BPalace
}).bindPopup('Buckingham Palace');


var BatterseaPark = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'img/icons8-marker-50.png',
  iconSize: [30, 30],
  iconAnchor: [15, 30],
  popupAnchor: [1, -30],
});

var marker2 = L.marker([51.478988287721876, -0.15648732182296068], {
  icon: BatterseaPark
}).bindPopup('Battersea Park');


var wembley = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'img/icons8-marker-50.png',
  iconSize: [30, 30],
  iconAnchor: [15, 30],
  popupAnchor: [1, -30],
});

var marker3 = L.marker([51.55619811605852, -0.2794567696109353], {
  icon: wembley
}).bindPopup('Wembley Stadium');

var bAirport = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'img/icons8-marker-50.png',
  iconSize: [30, 30],
  iconAnchor: [15, 30],
  popupAnchor: [1, -30],
});

var marker4 = L.marker([52.452333381857784, -1.7435316209846132], {
  icon: bAirport
}).bindPopup('Birmingham Airport');


L.featureGroup([marker1, marker2, marker3, marker4])
  .addTo(mymap);


var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
markers.addLayer(L.marker(marker1(map)));
map.addLayer(markers).addTo(mymap);
```

Is there something I’m doing wrong? I have added the relevant files to my html page, but when i refresh nothing seems to happen.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was correct but the code not, change it to:

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
marker1.addTo(markers);
marker2.addTo(markers);
marker3.addTo(markers);
marker4.addTo(markers);
markers.addTo(mymap);
```

And remove:

```
L.featureGroup([marker1, marker2, marker3, marker4])
  .addTo(mymap);
```